# Exporting tables from QuickBase

Tags: sql-server, database, quickbase

I am assigned with the task of taking all tables and records we have within QuickBase and importing them into a new database in MS SQL Server. I am an intern so this is new to me. I have been able to export all tables except two of them into CSV files so that I can import them into SQL Server. The two tables that will not export show a QuickBase error saying that the report is too large and the maximum number of bytes in report have been exceeded. My question is can someone recommend a work around for this? And also, do the CSV files have to be located on the server to import them, rather than have them stored on my machine?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export to CSV files, those files download from the browser onto your local machine, NOT the server. If you are running into issues with reports being too large, the filtering workaround above is a good enough.

The other possibility is to use the QuickBase API here:

http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html

Specifically, API_DoQuery is what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a QuickBase expert or anything, but some poking around indicates that is a limitation within QuickBase reporting.  One option would be to export those tables in sections:  Filter first for records older than 60 days, then for records 60 days old or newer; or some sort of filter like that that splits the tables into two or more chunks of mutually exclusive records.

When importing the CSVs with the import wizard, the wizard will give you the opportunity to navigate to the file.  If you are running SSMS on your local computer (which you should be), then the file will be accessible if it's on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try some existing OpenSource ETL tool to do that directly (QB->MSSQL) - i.e. without landing any intermediate CSV file.
Look for example at CloverETL (which I used to interact with QuickBase):
http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/quickbaserecordreader.html

They have a Community edition (free): http://www1.cloveretl.com/community-edition